# Table A has not column named B SQlite

Tags: sqlite

I created a table in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE `giocatori` ( `id` INTEGER, `nome_giocatore` TEXT, `pianeta` TEXT, `immagine` TEXT, `ruolo` TEXT, `valore_iniziale` INTEGER, `valore_skill1` INTEGER, `valore_skill2` INTEGER, `valore_skill3` INTEGER )
```

When i run this query:

```
INSERT INTO giocatori(id,nome_giocatore,pianeta,immagine,ruolo,valore_inziale,valore_skill1,valore_skill2,valore_skill3) VALUES( 26,'Yaya Amanzi','terra','Yaya Amanzi.jpg','ceo',18,22,25,28);
```

I get the following error:

```
table giocatori has no column named valore_inziale: INSERT INTO giocatori(id,nome_giocatore,pianeta,immagine,ruolo,valore_inziale,valore_skill1,valore_skill2,valore_skill3) VALUES( 26,'Yaya Amanzi','terra','Yaya Amanzi.jpg','ceo',18,22,25,28);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE ... `valore_iniziale` ...
INSERT INTO ...   valore_inziale,...
                           ^
```